# Работа с TCP сокетом на Android

Tags: java, android, сокет

Надо с клиента на андроиде коннектиться к сокету на компьютере, высылать туда сначала количество знаков в сообщении, а потом и само сообщение. Сразу после этого слушать ответ. У меня это вот так построено, но не работает:

```
try {
            Socket client = new Socket("ip", 8080);
            client.setSoTimeout(100);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

            String data_lenght = Integer.toString(data.length());
            String data_lenght_out = String.format("%10s", data_lenght).replace(' ', '0');

            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(data_lenght_out);
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(data);

            do{
                response = dataInputStream.readUTF();
            }while (response.length()<= 0);

            System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: какую ошибку дает?

Comment: потому, что с сетью нужно работать с треда, а  не  "main thread". в 4-5 андроиде "нельзя просто так добавить этот код в нажатие кнопки".

Comment: выдает
Error message :Read timed out
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Т.е. запускать как метод в другом потоке? Cоздаёть новый поток. Описать объект Runnable в конструкторе потока. Внутри созданного потока вызвать наш метод и запустить поток?
Thread myThread = new Thread( 
    new Runnable() { 
     public void run() {
      tcpconnect(); 
     }
    }
);